# I2C OTHER PINS IN RASPERRY PI FOR I2C LCD

Tags: gpio, pi-3b+, i2c

I am planning to put a power button on my raspberry pi 3b+ which uses the PIN 5 in order for me to shut it down and turn it on again when I wanted to. However, pin 5 is I2C CLOCK which is used for the I2C LCD. Now, my problem is I need them both. Are there alternative pins that I can use for my I2C LCD? Thank you so much!

Comment: Let me see. (1) Rpi4B has 5 I2C channels. (2) So you can use any of the I2C buses that do not use  GPIO pin5 as the I2C clock. (3) Reference: Python I2C LCD module (using PCA8574) V0.01 - WuSiYu, GitHub: https://github.com/WuSiYu/python-i2clcd

Comment: I am using raspi 3B+. Is that the same on 4B? and what pins exactly those other i2c buses located?

Comment: (1) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62757687/raspberry-pi-4-i2c-bus-not-working-correctly/62786449#62786449, (2) https://penzu.com/public/2450c7ae

Comment: Thank you for helping! I already fix my problem in the pins using this link https://www.instructables.com/Raspberry-PI-Multiple-I2c-Devices/ and I use your  LCD module because my current module is not working properly.

Comment: How nice you solved the problem. :)

Comment: Thank you also for the help! :)